# Spring ROO: JUnit test fails

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-roo

I am having trouble executing my Spring IntegrationTests, when i run the code below it is failing at the persist method:

```
@RooIntegrationTest(entity = Person.class)
public class PersonIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
    @Test
    public void testCountPeople(){
         Person personToPersist = PersonTestUtil.createTestPerson();

         personToPersist.persist();
         Long count = Person.countPeople();
         assertNotNull(personToPersist);
         assertTrue(personToPersist.countPeople() == 1);

    }
}
```

The Stack trace is below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)
    at org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$org_bixin_dugsi_domain_Person_Roo_Entity$org_bixin_dugsi_domain_Person$entityManager(Person_Roo_Entity.aj:95)
    at org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person.entityManager(Person.java:1)
    at org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$org_bixin_dugsi_domain_Person_Roo_Entity$org_bixin_dugsi_domain_Person$entityManager(Person_Roo_Entity.aj)
    at org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$org_bixin_dugsi_domain_Person_Roo_Entity$org_bixin_dugsi_domain_Person$persist(Person_Roo_Entity.aj:58)
    at org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person.persist(Person.java:1)
    at org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$org_bixin_dugsi_domain_Person_Roo_Entity$org_bixin_dugsi_domain_Person$persist(Person_Roo_Entity.aj)
    at org.bixin.dugsi.domain.PersonIntegrationTest.testCountPeople(PersonIntegrationTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have not injected the EntityManager and the related application context to your test.

Please try adding the following line above the class declaration.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml","/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml" })
```

and try making your test class to inhert from `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests`. Do keep in mind that you might have to implement authentication for some operations to be executed.

Your test class could look like below.

```
package com.myapp.test;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml","/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml" })
public class TestMyService extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    MyService service = new MyService();

    private void setUp() {
        //Do the setting up of your classes for the test
    }

    @Test
    public void testOperation() throws IOException {
        //My Test Code here
    }
}
```

Note that you should generally have a different context for your testing purposes.

Cheers.

Comment: When i add the @ContextConfiguration line that looks for the locations, i dont have the applicationContext-security.xml, so i get a file not found exception?

Comment: That is because I assumed Spring Security addon has been installed in your Roo project. You can remove the applicationContext-security.xml from the locations list and try. :)

Comment: i did just that and it removed the entity manager error i was getting but i the tests still fail with "Bean validation constraints violated when executing Automatic Bean validation"?

Comment: Ideally that should be a separate question, but I will answer here. You normally get that when you try to insert an invalid value to a persisted entity. Check if your values are correct in the test data, including the primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Springsource Tool Suite (or another Eclipse) try to clean the project. I think Eclipse someimes doesn't use the AJDT Compiler, specially at startup.

I don't remember this message from the Roo console, that uses maven under the hood.

Try "perform eclipse" from the Roo shell or even maven directly from the console (mvn clean install or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to inject the EntityManager and the application context.

Try something like this, it worked for me with Spring Roo:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;

import com.jitter.finance.analyzer.domain.Address;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml"})
public class EmTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Test
    public void checkEm(){
        Address a = new Address();
        a.setName("Primo");
        a.persist();

        Address b = new Address();
        b.setName("Secondo");
        b.persist();

        for(Address ad : Address.findAllAddresses()){
            System.out.println(ad.getName());
            assertEquals(ad.getName().charAt(ad.getName().length()-1), 'o');
        }
    }
}
```